# Writing a list of special characters in regex R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to write a list of special character in regex (Rstudio) but it don't work for one or two.

my list is : " / \ ? * : [ ] "

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- "test:e?xample"

str_replace_all(a, "[/ \ ? * : [ ]]", "_")
```

> [1] Output : "test_e_xample"

It works!

But with "[" doesn't

```
a <- "test:e[xample"

str_replace_all(a, "[/ \ ? * : [ ]]", "_")
```

> [1] Output : "test_e[xample"

Comment: Try with escaping those as those are meta characters `str_replace_all(a, "[/ \ ?*:\\[\\] ]", "_")#[1] "test_e_xample"`

Answer (score 2):

In base R, in a character class the metacharacter `"]"` must be the first.

```r
a <- "test:e?xample"
b <- "test:e[xample"

gsub("[][/\\?*:]", "_", a)
#> [1] "test_e_xample"

gsub("[][/\\?*:]", "_", b)
#> [1] "test_e_xample"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `stringr` package that uses the ICU regex flavor. In that regex flavor, in bracket expressions, the `[` and `]` characters are *special* and *thus must be escaped*:

```r
str_replace_all(a, "[/\\\\?*:\\[\\]]", "_")
```

Mind the double escaping of `\`, `[` and `]`. In an ICU bracket expression, two literal backslashes (four in the string literal) are used to match a literal `\` char.

If you plan to use base R equivalents, mind the difference between the two engines, TRE (used with `perl=FALSE` or with this argument omitted) and PCRE (when `perl=TRUE` is used):

```r
gsub("[][/\\?*:]", "_", a)
gsub("[][/\\\\?*:]", "_", a, perl=TRUE)
```

The first TRE based `gsub` contains a single literal `\` in the bracket expression, while the PCRE regex in the last `gsub` contains two literal backslashes (same as the ICU regex flavor). The thing is that the TRE regex bracket expression does not allow escaping special characters, that is why "smart placing" technique is used and the single backslash matches a literal backslash in the string.

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/xOIRUR):

```r
library(stringr)
a <- "test:e[xample\\"
str_replace_all(a, "[/\\\\?*:\\[\\]]", "_") # => [1] "test_e_xample_"
gsub("[][/\\?*:]", "_", a)                  # => [1] "test_e_xample_"
gsub("[][/\\\\?*:]", "_", a, perl=TRUE)     # => [1] "test_e_xample_"
```